# Is there any advantage in keeping dual video cards?

Tags: rendering, hardware

I just upgraded my graphics card from [Nvidia GTX 1660-Ti](https://www.nvidia.com/en-me/geforce/graphics-cards/gtx-1660-ti/) to [Nvidia RTX 2070 SUPER](https://www.nvidia.com/nl-nl/geforce/graphics-cards/rtx-2070-super/).

Is there any advantage in leaving the 1660-Ti in? The 2070 has shown a 30% increase in benchmark so far!

Comment: At least back in the days you could render with dual graphics cards, even if they were not the same model

Answer (score 2):

Yes leave it! You can render with both cards, and the CPU too, all at once. Just make sure you go into Blender parameters and turn them on under Cycles render parameters[image].